# get output of last Process on SSAS cube

Tags: sql-server, logging, cubes

I have processed a SSAS cube. After it was done processing, I hit the close button - and then realized that I should have saved the output.

I think SSAS stores the processing log as a text or XML file, but I do not know what folder to look into.

Can someone direct me to retrieving processing logs?

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing from UI (Management Studio or BI Dev Studio), on processing dialog click on Change Settings and go to the Dimension(Partition) key error tab. Or in SSMS right click on the object, dimension for example, and choose properties->Select a page: Error Configuration.

Or try somehwere in here: \Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.\OLAP\Config

Comment: I found where it will store Error Logs from your answer. I am looking for cube processing logs.

Comment: Did you ever find this?