# User Name Who Processed SSAS cube

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012

I tried with an MDX query to know the user name who processed the cube.

```
SELECT LAST_DATA_UPDATE FROM $system.mdschema_cubes
```

But this will not work.
Is there a way to know the user name who processed an SSAS tabular cube

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? returns an error? returns incorrect values? In what tools are you running this query?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the user who processed the cube is saved or recorded in any DMV.

Instead you will need to log trace events using one of the options outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31443880/5070440). This trace should run on the SSAS server on an ongoing basis. Later when you want to know who processed it you could scan back through the logs to determine who initiated the processing command.